# Selecting specific object(s) from list with Java

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

Probably some basic stuff I am missing here, but what is the best way to select objects matching some criteria from list? 
Say we have:

```
class MyObject {
    int id;
    String type;

    // getters..setters
}
```

I use it:

```
    List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    myObjects = getListOfObjects();
```

Now lets say that in the `myObjects` there are 10 items and 3 of them have `type=="bla"`. At the moment I am just looping thru all the objects and within the loop decide if I want it or not, but is there a better way?

I remember that in C# I used to have something like

```
myObjects.Where(x => x.type.equals("bla"));
```

PS, I am targeting Java 7 so no lambda for me yet.

Comment: Then you're already doing it right.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid looping through a list and intend to always retrieve groups of objects by type, consider a `Map<String,List<MyObject>>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without creating an index of some kind. So e.g. having `Map<String, Map<String, Set<MyObject>>>` you could then call `index.get("type").get("bla")`. But you would have to first construct this structure. This would be useful if a) there are no changes to the properties *AND* b) you have a LOT of objects. For 10 objects the performance is of no concern here and I would simply just do what you're doing right now and hide it inside some nice handy method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [LambdaJ library](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) and its [Lambda.exists](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/svn@1633/trunk/html/apidocs/ch/lambdaj/Lambda.html) method with some custom Hamcrest matcher. Then you could make your main code look like this:

```
if (exists(myObjects, typeIs("bla"))) { /* ... */ }
```

...provided that you create that custom matcher method `typeIs` by yourself. But I wouldn't go down this way if I had just one place with just 10 items in a list.

It also depends on your data: if your list is sorted, you could [do a binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465704/a-timer-for-seeing-how-long-an-algorithim-is-taking-is-saying-my-binary-search-t/10470181#10470181) on it. That's more useful if you have thousands of items in the list, though.

Finally, you could just use [Collection.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29): `myObjects.contains(blaElement)`, but that requires that the blaElement has such an `equals` method that returns "true" when the type matches.